# Как отключить все графики в highcharts?

Tags: highcharts

В highcharts при клике на имя графика он отключается. На скрине я показал для примера график Tokyo.
[image]
<sub>(источник: [joxi.ru](http://joxi.ru/Dr86G0WsBqgP26.jpg))</sub>
Необходимо создать кнопку, которая отключает все графики, чтобы потом можно было включить только необходимый.
То есть нужно сделать так, чтобы при клике на определенную кнопку (вне графика) было так:
[image]
<sub>(источник: [joxi.ru](http://joxi.ru/J2b10MNIpn7em6.jpg))</sub>
Как можно это организовать?

Comment: А доку покурить?

Comment: Курил.
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#legend
Если я не вижу, пожалуйста, ткните носом

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Накидал если интересно с добавлением элемента в legend

событие

```
plotOptions: {
            series: {
                events: {
                    legendItemClick: function (event) {
                        if (event.target.name === 'Отключить все')
                        {
                            for (var i in chart.series)
                            {
                                if (chart.series[i].name !== event.target.name)
                                {
                                    chart.series[i].hide();
                                } 
                            }
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
```

получение объекта в переменную

```
var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
        chart.addSeries({
            data: [],
            name: "Отключить все"
    });
```

правда с проверкой по имени не особо красиво

http://jsfiddle.net/startsevdenis/j766hwtj/

Comment: Там несколько другое. У меня на странице формируются 6 графиков. Их я всех определю на массив. Потом прогоню этот массив, в нем прогоню все series и применю к ним hide()
За идею спасибо, пригодится

Answer (score 3):

нашел решение. Действительно, маны курить нужно лучше. http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.hide